# how to decide type of element drawn by painter.drawPath(QPainterPath)

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter

I am drawing an outline of a glyph for given character using:

```
QString myfname="FreeMono.ttf";
QRawFont *myfont=new QRawFont(myfname,324,QFont::PreferDefaultHinting);
QChar mychars[]={'Q','B'};
int numofchars=3;
quint32 myglyphindexes[3];
int numofglyphs;
myfont->glyphIndexesForChars(mychars,numofchars,myglyphindexes,&numofglyphs);
QPainterPath mypath=myfont->pathForGlyph(myglyphindexes[0]);
```

This path I am drawing on pixmap using

```
painter.drawPath(mypath)
```

I want to know how this path is drawn.
I mean what type of curves or lines this outline contains.
For this I tried this:

```
QPointF mypoints[49];
for(int i=0; i<mypath.elementAt(i); i++)
    {
        mypoints[i]=mypath.elementAt(i);
    }
```

This gives me array of points.
But how these points are connected with each other like using a line or curve. How can I know that?
Also is this a correct approach?
What I need to improve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QPainterPath::elementAt()` returns an object of type [QPainterPath::Element](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qpainterpath-element.html#isCurveTo), not a `QPoint` (it has a QPointF operator defined).

You can use code like this:

```
const QPainterPath::Element &elem = path.elementAt(ii);

// You can use the type enum.
qDebug() << elem.type;

// Or you can use the functions.
if (elem.isCurveTo()) {
    qDebug() << "curve";
} else if (elem.isLineTo()) {
    qDebug() << "line";
} else if (elem.isMoveTo()) {
    qDebug() << "move";
}
```

Comment: hey thanks a lot. I was also able to reconnect these points with lineTo, curveTo and moveTo functions. Thanks once again!

Answer (score 1):

sashoalm is correct, but I would just like to add that you can use `path.elementCount()` to know how many elements are in your `QPainterPath`.

Hence, it would look like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<mypath.elementCount(); i++)
{
    const QPainterPath::Element & elem = mypath.elementAt(i);
    qDebug() << elem.type;

    // Or you can use the functions.
    if (elem.isCurveTo()) {
        qDebug() << "curve";
    } else if (elem.isLineTo()) {
        qDebug() << "line";
    } else if (elem.isMoveTo()) {
        qDebug() << "move";
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks..I used the same function to calculate number of elements